# Can you train tesseract with images instead of text and a font?

Tags: ocr, tesseract, training-data

In the tesseract [documentation](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract-4.00) a method of training with sample text and a font is explained.
I used *jTessBoxEditor* but works pretty much like the tesseract training tools.
I got somewhat acceptable results with this, but I guess the optimal solution would be training tesseract with the actual kind of images it will have to recognize anyway.
As I only need to recognize digits, I can cut by hand each of them, maybe many versions of each digit, and train tesseract with those images, even setting the boxes by hand.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to train tesseract4, you can use [ocrd-train](https://github.com/OCR-D/ocrd-train) 
you basically prepare images corresponding to each line of text with their ground truth and it will do all the remaining work for you.